# how to copy variable to [clipboard] in django template

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, django-templates

How do I copy a variable from inside the html page of Django templates?

```
render(request, 'doc.html', {'stack': stack, 'text':text,})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question may not seem clear enough to describe what you want or describe your problem, but some of my guesses for the solution are that you need to use js code in your template, specifically `document.text.select()` and `document.execCommand('copy')`.

Perhaps the following example will suffice:

in html code

```
<html>
<body>
     <button style="background:green; text-align:center;" onclick="CopyText()">Copy Text</button>
     <input style="text-align:center;" type="text" value="{{text}}"id="yourtext">
</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
{% block scripts %}
<script>
  function CopyText() {
  var text = document.getElementById('yourtext')
  text.select();
  document.execCommand('copy')
}
</script>
{% endblock scripts %}
```

In the example shown above, we used the value of the variable that you send to the template as a default value in the text tag, and then we specify the text through the tag's ID `yourtext`, and then execute the copy command.
It may not seem perfect but it is enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi! it worked for me
I had thought that the value should be passed as args to the function "CopyText" header and copy, but I failed to do so. But there is no problem with this solution.

Comment: As for sending the value as arguments to the header of the function it is possible JS:"```function CopyText(text)```" and Html "```CopyText({{text}})```", but I haven't tested that.
I do not know whether it will work or not, especially if we talk about implementing the following commands "```text.select();```" and "```document.execCommand('copy')```".
good luck

Comment: Oh you're right, maybe there's a different solution that fits the idea, thanks.